# Test class for a Batch scheduler

Tags: apex, unit-test

I can't understand how to write a test class for a batch scheduler.
Here is my scheduler:

```
global class UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler implements Schedulable {
public static String sched = '0 00 00 * * ?'; //Every Day at Midnight

global static String scheduleMe() {
    UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler SC = new UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler();
    return System.schedule('OARs sync every day at midnight', sched, SC);
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJob myBatchObject = new UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJob();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject, 200);
}
```

}

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest
public class UltimateParent18Digit_BatchSchr_Test {

@isTest
static void testScheduler () {
            
    Test.startTest();
    
    String jobId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',
  UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler.sched, 
     new UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler());
    
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

It compiles, but it only gives me 57% code coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call the `scheduleMe` method:

```
Test.startTest();
UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler.scheduleMe();
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, helped me figure it out again! Here is what I've learned. The middle part of my scheduler `scheduleMe()` has to be commented (removed). You use it only once (when you schedule the batch). When a job scheduled, it can't be scheduled again, which is what the test class is trying to do. With that said, If I use the code you posted, it will give me an error ".. already scheduled". So, the only part that has to be tested is the `execute()`.

Comment: @Slava The job name has to be unique. I'd suggest you make the job name configurable for your unit test, something like `@TestVisible static String jobName = 'OARs sync every day at midnight';` and in your unit test, `UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler.jobName = 'Unit Test for OARs Sync'; UltimateParent18Digit_BatchJobScheduler.scheduleMe();`

Comment: Job name configurable, makes sense. Thanks